# How to set log direction in SCDF

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have tried 2 ways to setting log direction:
_ The 1st way is changing LOG_FILE in logback-spring.xml:

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" 
              value="D:/logs/test" />
```

_ The 2nd way is set application.properties

```
spring.cloud.deployer.local.workingDirectoriesRoot=D:\\Deploy
```

However, These cases do not works, the log of task when i launched is written on `java.io.tmpdir (C:/..../temp/)`.
Do i need configure the same in batch project which is launched by SCDF.
 
How can i configure the log folder of `SCDF` and their tasks.

Comment: did you get this answer? I am also looking for the same. Can u pls write your solution if you get for this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using scdf in local environment:

1. create /config/application.yml
2. add the following lines in application.yml

   ```
   spring:
     profiles:
       active: local
   logging:
     file: logs/test.log
   ```

Comment: where can we create the /config/application.yml? I mean in which spring cloud dataflow repo?

Comment: If you have local installation, put config directory where your spring-cloud-dataflow-server is located